UndefinedFile: could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/14/extension/vector.control": No such file or directory
I'm trying to run postgres along with pgvector but getting this error: UndefinedFile: could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/14/extension/vector.control": No such file or directory on ubuntu 24.04
Here's what my code block looks like in jupyter notebook:
async def main():
    conn = await psycopg.AsyncConnection.connect(dbname='pgvector_example', autocommit=True)
    await create_schema(conn)
    await insert_data(conn)

    # perform queries in parallel
    results = await asyncio.gather(semantic_search(conn, query), keyword_search(conn, query))
    results = rerank(query, results)
    print(results)

#use this in Jupyter notebook
await main()

`
I've already installed pgvector and postgres as mentioned here in docs,and created pgvector_example db in postgres.
On running CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pgvector; in postgres, I got the same error
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/14/extension/vector.control": No such file or directory
Edit
On running SELECT * FROM pg_available_extensions; it outputs list of extensions and does NOT contain pg_vector

How did you install PostgreSQL and does this installation include the code for the pg_vector extension? Check your database: SELECT * FROM pg_available_extensions;

On running SELECT * FROM pg_available_extensions; it outputs list of extensions and does NOT contain pg_vector

That means that pgvector has not been installed properly. That's the first thing you have to fix, check all the steps you took to see what went wrong.
